# Get component's background image ("inherited" from parent's larger background image) and make it transparent

Tags: java, swing, graphics, transparent, bufferedimage

Say that I have a JPanel with an image drawn on it as a background via `paintComponent()`, and this panel contains some buttons with icons. The buttons don't have their own background and "inherit" the panel's background. I know how to make a button's icon translucent with `AlphaComposite`, but how can I get just the button's background image (which is ***part*** of the JPanel's background image since the buttons are opaque and are painted over the panel's background) and make it transparent, instead of the icon? I don't even know if this is possible...

The following code just makes the button's icon transparent.

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestPanel extends JPanel {

    private final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("path\\to\\image\\file"));
    private BufferedImage img;

    public TestPanel() {

        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("path\\to\\background\\image"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {}

        ImageIcon fadedIcon = getTranslucentImageIcon(icon, 0.5f);
        JButton button = new JButton(fadedIcon);
        button.setRolloverIcon(icon);
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        button.setOpaque(false);
        button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        button.setFocusPainted(false);
        this.add(button);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (img != null) {
          return new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
        }
        return super.getPreferredSize();
    }

    private BufferedImage getTranslucentImage(BufferedImage oldImg, float alpha) {
        int w = oldImg.getWidth();
        int h = oldImg.getHeight();
        BufferedImage newImg = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT);
        Graphics2D g2d = newImg.createGraphics();
        g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, alpha));
        g2d.drawImage(oldImg, null, 0, 0);
        g2d.dispose();
        return newImg;
    }

    private ImageIcon getTranslucentImageIcon(Icon oldIcon, float alpha) {
        int w = oldIcon.getIconWidth();
        int h = oldIcon.getIconHeight();
        BufferedImage oldImg = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) oldImg.getGraphics();
        oldIcon.paintIcon(null, g2d, 0, 0);
        BufferedImage newImg = getTranslucentImage(oldImg, alpha);
        g2d.dispose();
        return new ImageIcon(newImg);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPanel());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

You just need 2 images to reproduce it (the background image should be larger to make my point clear).

P.S. I would also like to know if I'm doing the whole thing correct (more specific the methods `getTranslucentImage` and `getTranslucentImageIcon`) or if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: Just to clarify, the button doesn't "inherit" anything, it simply paints "over"

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand what it is you want to achieve.  From the sounds of it, you want to "grab" the area under the button and paint it over it (using an `AlphaComposite`)? If so, I'm not sure it can be done. The paint engine is clever enough to know that it doesn't need to paint the area under the button, there fore there's no guarantee that the space is actually painted...

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes this is what I want. I don't know if it can be done either... As for your first comment, I say "inherits" just to be clear that the button's area "shows" the parent's (JPanel) background (it is not opaque and it doesn't have its own background). I didn't know how else to say it...

Comment: I edited a bit based on your first comment

Answer (score 3):

I'll put this here as comments aren't a suitable for the formatting.

As to your "translucent" methods, they seem fine to me.  The only change I might make is create a compatible buffered image instead.  This will (amongst other things) ensure that the colour model is the same and make it faster to render...

```
protected BufferedImage createCompatibleImage(int width, int height, int transparency) {
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice gs = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    GraphicsConfiguration gc = gs.getDefaultConfiguration();
    return gc.createCompatibleImage(width, height, transparency);
}

private BufferedImage getTranslucentImage(BufferedImage oldImg, float alpha) {
    int w = oldImg.getWidth();
    int h = oldImg.getHeight();
    BufferedImage newImg = createCompatibleImage(w, h, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
    Graphics2D g2d = newImg.createGraphics();
    g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, alpha));
    g2d.drawImage(oldImg, null, 0, 0);
    g2d.dispose();
    return newImg;
}
```

**UPDATED with extended answer**

I order to achieve what you want, you would need a clean version of the parent component.  That is a copy without any children.  You would then need size and paint this copy to a off screen buffer (like a buffered image) and then extract the portion of the image you want (or paint the sub image based on your requirements).

To be frank. What you are doing is simply easier...

Comment: But how can I extract the portion of the image that I want? This portion depends on the child which is the button. The portion I want is everything else inside the button's area except its icon.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem.  Hence the reason why you would need a "clean" copy.

Comment: I might have a solution, but I crashed my PC testing it ;)